# How to change the Javascript result to 4 decimal points?

Tags: javascript

I have this function, and I have tried to use toFixed(4) to make the result into 4 decimal points but it's not working.

```
function fncSum()
{  
    ParseFloat(document.frmMain.percentage.value).toFixed(4) = (parseFloat(document.frmMain.received.value) +
    parseFloat(document.frmMain.wronglyc.value))/
     parseFloat(document.frmMain.wronglyfiled.value);

}
```

Can anyone help me with this one? Change the frmMain value to 4 decimal points.

Comment: you can't assign to the result of a function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Math.round(number * 10000) / 10000` to round to 4 decimal places.

@Tushar's answer is also valid

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains errors. Use `toFixed()` on the combined result of the expression and then updated the value of the element.

```
function fncSum() {
    document.frmMain.percentage.value = ((parseFloat(document.frmMain.received.value) + parseFloat(document.frmMain.wronglyc.value)) / parseFloat(document.frmMain.wronglyfiled.value)).toFixed(4);
}
```